# How to extract edge attributes from a directed graph shortest path:

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to graphs and expect this is something fairly basic.

I have a directed graph (a hydrology network) and I want to grab an attribute from the edges in a shortest path.  For example:

```
library(igraph)
gdf <- data.frame(from = c(1,2,3,5), to = c(2,3,4,3), id = c("A","B","C","D"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(gdf, directed = TRUE)
idx <- shortest_paths(g, 1, 3, output = "epath")$epath[[1]]
igraph::edge_attr(g, "id", idx)
```

Which returns:

```
[1] "A" "B"
```

If I want to get the labels for the shortest path to the end of the network:

```
idx <- shortest_paths(g, 1, 4, output = "epath")$epath[[1]]
igraph::edge_attr(g, "id", idx)
```

I get:

```
Warning message:
In shortest_paths(g1, 1, 4, output = "epath") :
  At structural_properties.c:740 :Couldn't reach some vertices
```

And `idx` is:

```
+ 0/4 edges from b8aaa81 (vertex names):
```

For this last one I would have expected to get `[1] "A" "B" "C"`

How do I get the labels for a shortest path that includes the final vertex of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way that you are referring to the vertices. Notice that the vertex ids do not line up with the vertex labels.

```
vertex_attr(g)
$name
[1] "1" "2" "3" "5" "4"
```

When you write `shortest_paths(g, 1, 4, output = "epath")$epath[[1]]`

It will take the first and fourth nodes which have labels "1" and "5".  This is failing because there is no path from "1" to "5".  I believe you meant

```
idx <- shortest_paths(g, "1", "4", output = "epath")$epath[[1]]
igraph::edge_attr(g, "id", idx)
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

`